# Loop function ith timer before if statement

Tags: javascript, loops

```
btnRoll.addEventListener ('click', function() {
if (isPlaying) {
  diceElement.classList.remove ('hidden');
  function changeDiceImage () {
    // Display number on the dice
    const diceNumber = Math.trunc (Math.random () * 6) + 1;
    diceElement.src = `dice${diceNumber}.png`;
    i++;
    let timer = setTimeout (changeDiceImage, 200);
    if (i === 5) {
      clearTimeout (timer);
      number = diceNumber;
    }
    timer;
  }
  let i = 0;
  let number = 0;
  changeDiceImage ();
  if (number !== 1) {
    currentScore += number;
    document.getElementById (`current--${activePlayer}`).textContent = currentScore;
  } else {
    switchActivePlayer ();
  }
}
})
```

I try to loop function (that randomly change images with dice) and also last dice number go to `number` then to `score`.
In result i receive NaN value instead of number.
How to fix the problem?

Comment: `changeDiceImage ();` returns right away. You need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: so, `currentScore` is `NaN`.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, currentScore is NaN (undefined)

Comment: After first time changeDiceImage () end, main function continue to if (number !== 1)  and only after if (number !== 1) end changeDiceImage() continue loop. After loop if statement doesnt proceed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a couple tools...

A function that returns a promise which resolves after ms...

```
async function after(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

A function that returns a randomly shuffled array of `[1..6]`, due to [Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/)...

```
function shuffleDie() {
  let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  let m = 6, t, i;

  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

The OP's aim: present a random sequence of die images and return (a promise that resolves to) the last number in the random sequence...

```
async function changeDiceImage(diceElement) {
  const numbers = shuffleDie();
  for (let number of numbers) {
    diceElement.src = `dice${number}.png`;
    await after(ms);
  }
  return numbers[5];  // resolve to the last number
}
```

Use these to clean up the eventListener significantly...

```
btnRoll.addEventListener ('click', async () => {
  if (isPlaying) {
    diceElement.classList.remove ('hidden');
    let number = await changeDiceImage(diceElement);

    if (number !== 1) {
      currentScore += number;
      document.getElementById (`current--${activePlayer}`).textContent = currentScore;
    } else {
      switchActivePlayer ();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: All good but in changeDiceImage(diceElement) number return values from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of those specified (randomly) in the array. Why so?

Comment: Found a problem: in for (let number in numbers) need instead 'in' use 'of'. Problem solved. Very thankfull for your help:)

Comment: Oh, good catch.  Sorry about that.  I found a problem, also, which is that number will never === -1.  Sounds like a game-specific fix having to do with when you should switch players.

Comment: No problem:) I'm a beginner (only studding) JS and you opened a lot of new things in JS for me.